# Remove the brackets in json?

Tags: php, json

How can I get rid of the brackets below for json processing?

```
[{"success":true,"filename":"bialding_and_rebialding_plymouth02.jpg"},{"success":true,"filename":"bialding_and_rebialding_plymouth03.jpg"},{"success":true,"filename":"bialding_and_rebialding_plymouth04.jpg"}]
```

The result above is processed by the class below into an array,

```
function handle_upload($upload_directory)
    {
        # Loop the code according to the number of files.
        for($i = 1; $i <= $this->total; $i++)
        {
            ...

            if ($this->file->save($upload_directory.$name_filtered.'.'.$file_extension , $i-1))
            {
                $message[] = array('success'=>true,'filename'=>$name_filtered.'.'.$file_extension);
            }
            else 
            {
                $message[] = array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' . 'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
            }
        }

        return $message;
    }
```

Then I use `json_encode` to turn the array into json format,

```
$uploader = new uploader();
$result = $uploader->handle_upload('uploads/');

echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

But I only need this in my result without the brackets,

```
{"success":true,"filename":"bialding_and_rebialding_plymouth02.jpg"},{"success":true,"filename":"bialding_and_rebialding_plymouth03.jpg"},{"success":true,"filename":"bialding_and_rebialding_plymouth04.jpg"}
```

Comment: Without the brackets, your json string will be invalid. a JSON string can contain only a single value. With the brackets, it's an array or objects. Without the brackets, it's a series of individual comma-separated objects - invalid.

Comment: that is not valid json anymore.

Comment: Why don't you want the `[]`?  What are you going to do with the resulting string?

Comment: My mistake - I thought the brackets should be there. I'm new to json - sorry!

Comment: @lauthiamkok: The brackets *should* be there, it's not valid JSON otherwise.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($result), ENT_NOQUOTES));` ?

Comment: Please never mangle json strings by using string functions.  Decode the data, fix it, re-encode the data <-- this is the safe technique.

Answer (score 3):

You can pull out the json and return just that by doing the following inside your function:

```
return $message[0];  //  only json
```

or you can return it all and remove it afterwards:

```
$uploader = new uploader();
$result1 = $uploader->handle_upload('uploads/');
$result2 = $result[0];
```